# Declaring date from MongoDB as correct Type

Tags: mongodb, playframework, reactivemongo

I am attempting to match a *case class* to a *mongoDb* (0.12) however one field is date and I am coming up with this *runtime error*:

> [JsResultException:
>   JsResultException(errors:List((/date,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.date),WrappedArray())))))]

A document from my MongoDB collection looks like this:

```
   { "_id": ObjectID("59c33152ca2abb344c575152"), "date": ISODate("2017-09-26T00:00:00Z"), "population": 1200 }
```

And my *case class* is:

```
   case class MyClass(_id: Option[BSONObjectID] = None, date: Date = new Date, population: Int = 0)
```

I have tried various combinations. Can anyone see what the issue might be? After this I intend to convert it to a *String* and output it onscreen. Thanks

---

Just to add that I have also got this *companion object*:

```
   object MyClass {
     implicit val myClassFormat = Json.format[MyClass]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to describe the right Json `Format` for the Date type, like this one (using `org.joda.time.DateTime`):

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
import play.api.libs.json._

object myClass {
    val ISO8601 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"
    implicit val dateFormat: Format[DateTime] = Format[DateTime](Reads.jodaDateReads(ISO8601), Writes.jodaDateWrites(ISO8601))
}
```

Comment: Thanks however some of your code appears to be deprecated in *scala 2.12* . Also I have edited the question to show the *companion object* that is formatting the *case class* - not sure if there is anything specific that needs to be done here for the *date*.

Comment: To my mind you will have to declare an implicit `Format[Date]` before your `Format[MyClass]`, did you try that already?

Comment: I am using **automated mapping in Play** [https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated] so I thought that this would ensure that all fields are formatted correctly. I did try this as you suggested but it didn't reference the class field: `implicit val weatherDateFormat = Json.format[Date]`